# google maps v3.36 Infowindow is hiding the marker

Tags: google-maps

As per https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases, the new release 3.36 "Infowindow has been improved."

But now the infowindow hides the marker. In v3.35 it used to sit nicely on top of the marker with a pointed tip. How can I achieve the old behavior ? I did try setting "pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(200,0)" but that didn't help.

[image: This is older version v3.35].
[image: This is new version v3.36]

Notice how with new version v3.36, marker is not visible as it is hiding behind the info window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are affected by the Maps JS version rollover, the error is occurring whenever a reserved word in the ECMAscript is used in your program, to fix this, you should change the reserved word you are using that is affecting your Maps JS.

There is also a workaround for this, you may specify the version of your map to 3.34,which will look like the code below:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&v=3.34&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Please also note that this has been recognized in the Issue tracker, you may visit this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/125539051) to learn more.